# How to revisit a deck numerous times a day

Tags: anki

I am in a dire situation where in I can’t use Anki to the fullest. I am learning German, and using Anki for vocab words.

All I want is after I have finished a deck, and it says “Congratulations! You have finished this deck for now.” - how do I revisit that deck again for any number of times during the day if I need to go over those words again?

I want to override the function of Anki displaying those decks to me after 3/4 days. Thanks.

I have already tried clicking on "rebuild" and empty, but to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the "Options" for your deck you can set all kinds of timings related to your cards. You can emulate the behaviour you want.

Relevant timings for you are `"New Cards > Learning Steps` and `"Lapses" > Relearning steps`. The way they are set up by default is that every new card gets shown again (on success) after 1 minute and then again after 10 minutes, while a lapse (old card that you forgot) gets shown after 10 minutes.
You can set this field to something like `1m 10m 60m 300m` so they are shown again later in the same day.

When I used anki like this, I also set the 'graduating interval' (what happens after the 300m) to three days and the 'easy interval' to just one day. You can experiment a lot with these settings.

Another way to go is "Custom Study". If you select a deck, you can click "Custom Study" in the bottom of the pane. Among other things, this lets you review cards that are not 'due' yet.

Comment: Thank you so much for this kind help. Can you please recommend a setting where in I get to review all the cards atleast thrice a day, and then the forgotten ones after every alternate day. I really need to drill down on them. Many thanks again.

Comment: @Rajat I added another paragraph adressing this - anki lets you look at all your cards if you want. I would recommend however, that you trust the principle of spaced repetition and do not review all cards several times a day.

Comment: I understand that. But, I am likely to lose a touch with new language or word which I haven't encountered ever in my life just after one-visit of the deck. The repeat happened after 3 days, and by then I had forgotten many words. And then the deck never repeated.

How do I use that "Custom Study" option to review the deck again to atleast drill down a few new words? I am new to Anki, and unfamiliar with these options currently.

Comment: @Rajat "Custom Study" opens a dialog to select cards from the deck, for example, cards that would be shown to you in some days. But your problem sounds like you need more steps in "Relearning Steps", change it to something like "10m 20m 100m" or whatever and you forgotten cards will be shown several times. There are lots of blogs and youtube-tutorials about how to customize those things, check them out to get some ideas. The goal of spaced repetition is to free you from the time-consuming burden of reviewing everything every day.

Comment: But really those are things you need to try for a while and see how it works for your learning style, personal situation and the information you need to learn.

Comment: Will definitely experiment around with those. Thank you so much for helping me out with this. I owe it to you.

Comment: @Rajat Viel Erfolg beim Lernen :)